# Stuck on a confidence interval question:

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

An interval estimate for the average distance car tyres lasted during their "lifetime" was reported to be 33112 km to 36775 km. This interval estimate was based on a sample of 47 tyres. The variance of the lifetime was determined from previous studies to be 44885212 km squared. What level of confidence can be attributed to this interval estimate? State your answer as a percentage, correct to the nearest whole number.

I've tried using the formula n = (z-crit*standard deviation/standard error)^2 but it didn't seem to work. My answer ended up being 1... obviously. Not sure what else I can try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to avoid downvotes and/or closing you should add your own efforts on this and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, sure.